# Custom sort using array causes excel crash

Tags: excel, vba

I am using the following code to sort in custom way using array of values on which I would like to sort

```
Sub Sort_Custom()
Dim n           As Long

Application.AddCustomList Array("A", "D", "B", "-")
n = Application.CustomListCount

With Sheets("Data")
    .Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Sort Key1:=.Range("E1"), Header:=xlYes, OrderCustom:=n + 1
End With

Application.DeleteCustomList n
End Sub
```

The code works fine and as expected ..
But the problem appears after running the code and when saving the code, the application crashes and I have to restart
Any ideas how to fix that?

[image: Here's a snapshot of the error]

---

I have another working code and that is well after the running it, the save process works with no problem

```
Sub NewTest()
Dim w           As Worksheet
Dim x As Variant

'x = "A"
Set w = Worksheets("Data")

With w.Sort
    .SortFields.Clear
    .SortFields.Add w.Range("E1"), CustomOrder:="A"
    .Header = xlYes
    .SetRange w.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    .Apply
End With
End Sub
```

Just a little point I need .. which is using a variable instead of directly using "A"
I tried x="A" and used x after CustomOrder:= but this doesn't work

Comment: how does it crash? Do you get an error? The program closes?

Comment: also what is your intention with `CurrentRegion`?  Likely, whatever "region" is being returned is not a logical set of cells that can be sorted.  You can check what it's trying to sort with: `Sheets("Data").range("A1").CurrentRegion.select` and see what cells are selected at that point,  (or `Debug.print Sheets("Data").range("A1").CurrentRegion.address` and check the immediate window with ctrl+g)

Comment: CurrentRegion to refer to the whole range from A1 to E & lastRow

Comment: are you sure? did you check?  If so, try using the range temporarily hard-coded instead of using `currentregion`

Comment: In the immediate window I typed `?Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Address` and this returns the expected range `$A$1:$E$1490`

Comment: okay then it could likely be related to the custom sort order number you are specifying. Personally, i'd hard code te range for now for the sake of eliminating possible culprits. Also note that you didn't specify the Sheet in your `?` debug window statement.  I know it seems silly but its good to verify when stuck; maybe there's a different sheet on top currently.

Comment: I hard-coded the range in that way `.Range("A1:E1490").Sort ` and the code works with no problem. The real problem is when saving the file ..!!!

Comment: ohhh I missed the word "save" sorry.. First step: re-boot.  This is important after repeated crashes because there could be something left partially loaded in memory messing with it

Comment: There is an issue with: 'OrderCustom:=n + 1' where it should be 'CustomOrder:=n'